# how to stop animation from wexecuting too early

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors, css-animations

I'm trying to use animate.css 's fadeInUp function but it keeps working prematurely.
At first I did not think it worked, then I refreshed the page and it animated but only when I hit the refresh button.
Here's the code

```
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid mt-4 claim animate__animated animate__fadeInUp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried decreasing the speed of the animation, which it showed I did, only that it still worked just when I hit the refresh button and the page is loading.
So what I want to know is how to make the animation work after loading not during.

Comment: You should read the documents of that library

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the animation-delay attribute like:

animation-delay: 6s; (here 6s means animation will start after 6 seconds)

Use animation-duration to change the speed of the animation liuke:

animation-duration: 10s; (here 10s means animation will complete in 10 seconds)
Thanks.